# How to animate subview so it only animates within bounds of frame?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm trying to get a slide in animation without animating across the screen. I only want the image to slide into the frame of it's container as if you were watching a wall with a window in it and somebody walked by the window.

```
    let image = self.overlayImageView[cell1]

    image.clipsToBounds = true

    image.center.x -= image.bounds.width

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.75, animations: { () -> Void in

        image.center.x += image.bounds.width

    }) { (Bool) -> Void in

        //completion handler

    }
```

[image]

UPDATE:

```
    cell.clipsToBounds = true

    button.clipsToBounds = true

    let image = UIImage(named: answeredCorrectlyImage)

    button.addSubview(cell) //this was all that was missing

    cell.center.x -= cell.bounds.width

    if users == 1...5 && cell.hidden == true {

        button.enabled = false

        cell.hidden = false

        cell.image = image

        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: { () -> Void in

            cell.center.x += cell.bounds.width

        })
```

Comment: Is image a subview of the container view when the animation starts?

Comment: The image is not a subview. The bottom view is a button, the top view is a UIImageView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clip `image` to its parent's bounds. Currently you have image set to clip to bounds. This would work if you were moving the image layer within this view, but since you're trying to move your image view, you need to have a parent that clips it.

Comment: Oh wow, that was a lot easier than I was making it out to be.